# IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature. - even though MetadataAddress is set

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, firebase-authentication, jwt, openid-connect

I am trying to validate the OpenId Connect token from Google Firebase on my backend.
My code is:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddJwtBearer(options =>
       {
           options.Audience = "<firebase project id>";
           options.MetadataAddress = "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com";
           options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
           {
               ValidateAudience = true,
               ValidateIssuer = true,
               ValidateLifetime = true,
               ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
               RequireAudience = true,
               RequireExpirationTime = true,
               RequireSignedTokens = true,
               ValidIssuer = $"https://securetoken.google.com/{options.Audience}"
           };
       });
```

However my token is not accepted due to missing security keys:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[7]
      Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.
```

The `kid` of my token matches one of the key IDs at https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com. Therefore I don't understand that error. Shouldn't ASP.Net Core download the keys automatically from the address provided via `MetadataAddress`? What am I missing?